# Powershell command for enabling Group-Writeback state of an Azure AD Security Group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am trying to do a bulk operation to set Group Write-back state of Azure AD groups to "Security" but am not able to achieve this using powershell.

Is there a possible way to automate this using powershell?

Desired field that needs to be updated:

[image]

Tried using Set-Azure AD command and set -securityenabled=$true

Answer (score 0):

> You can make use of **`Microsoft.Graph.Beta`** module to enable **Group writeback** state of an Azure AD Security Group.

If you don't have that module installed, run below command to install it:

```
Install-Module  Microsoft.Graph.Beta  -AllowClobber
```

I have one Azure AD group named **`SriGroup`** with Group writeback state as **No writeback** like below:

[image]

Now, I ran below PowerShell script to set Group writeback state of above group to **Security**:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Groups

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Group.ReadWrite.All"
$params = @{
    writebackConfiguration = @{
        isEnabled = $true
        onPremisesGroupType = "universalSecurityGroup"
    }
}
$groupId = "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx"
Update-MgBetaGroup -GroupId $groupId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, Group writeback state changed to **Security** successfully as below:

[image]

To do a **bulk** operation of setting Group writeback state to **"Security"**, you can use below modified script:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Groups

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Group.ReadWrite.All"
$params = @{
    writebackConfiguration = @{
        isEnabled = $true
        onPremisesGroupType = "universalSecurityGroup"
    }
}

$groupIds = @("id1", "id1", "id3")

foreach ($groupId in $groupIds) {
    Update-MgBetaGroup -GroupId $groupId -BodyParameter $params
}
```

Make sure to use **latest** PowerShell version while running above scripts.

**Reference:**
[Update-MgBetaGroup (Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Groups)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.beta.groups/update-mgbetagroup?view=graph-powershell-beta)

Comment: I am getting this error message when I run the above code:



I also installed the Microsoft.Graph.Beta module. Please help

Comment: Could you include what error you are getting?

Comment: 1st error:Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.33.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: 2nd Error: Update-MgBetaGroup : The 'Update-MgBetaGroup' command was found in the module 'Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Groups', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 
'Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Groups'.
At line:11 char:1
+ Update-MgBetaGroup -GroupId $groupId -BodyParameter $params
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Update-MgBetaGroup:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule

Comment: That error usually occurs if module is not installed properly. Please refer this similar issue [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/1196#issuecomment-1366701105) where it suggests uninstalling all graph related modules and reinstall them with `-Scope AllUsers` option. Try using latest PowerShell Version 7.